# Where to insert this snippet in functions.php file of WordPress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

The entire **functions.php** file in my child theme currently is:

```
<?php
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
   function theme_enqueue_styles() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-rtl.css' );
   }
 ?>

<?php
  // Display 6 products per page. Goes in functions.php
  add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 6;' ), 20 );
?>
```

I need to add a snippet to change the footer. I got this snippet from WordPress support, but every place I insert it I get a syntax error. I've inserted it multiple ways, properly nested in tags, but my site always breaks. Could a kind person please show me how the entire **functions.php** files should look, after I insert this snippet?

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_remove_footer_credit', 10 );

function custom_remove_footer_credit () {
  remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_credit', 20 );
  add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'custom_storefront_credit', 20 );
} 

function custom_storefront_credit() {
?>
  <div class="site-info">
     &copy; <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' ' . get_the_date( 'Y' ); ?>
  </div><!-- .site-info -->
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: parent-style is already use, find another unique name for rtl.css, wordpress will chose style and not rtl.css

Comment: better show us error. also am agree with @Fil

Comment: Yes..Share your syntax error whatever you are getting after inserting it in `functions.php` file ?

Comment: If I insert snippet directly before the first php close tag I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/robertri/public_html/woo/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/functions.php on line 6`

Comment: Also, I don't fully understand @Fil but I think he's right. I added that second `wp_enque_style` line becasue the storefront theme has two stylesheets. I was guessing that I had to add that line for every stylesheet in parent theme?

Comment: Yes, Here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: and here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want PHP code to execute, it will need to be after a PHP open tag. If it’s positioned after a PHP close tag, it will be displayed as plain text on your website, which you do not want.

Comment: Sadly this does not answer the question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34190721)